# Access queryset of a modelChoiceField in template tag

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a model which has a color field

```
class EventCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 10)
    color = models.CharField(max_length = 8)
```

and Event model

```
class Event(models.Model):
    #fields
    category = models.ForeignKey(EventCategory)
```

How can I access the modelChoice queryset in my template tag. Doing something like that doesn't work (suppose i have a form sent to my template)

```
<select name="category" id="id_category">
    {%for category in form.category.queryset%}
        <option value="{{category.pk}} style="background-color:{{category.color}};">category.name</option>
    {%endfor%}  
</select>
```

I know in my python files I can do something like this:

```
form = EventForm()
for c in form.fields['category'].queryset:
    print c
```

And will give me its EventCategory instance. But how can i do the same thing inside a template tag?

EDIT Got it!!!

```
{%for category in in form.category.field.queryset%}
    etc
{%endfor%}
```

Comment: If you have found an Answer to your own Question, please add it as a proper answer and accept it. This will improve things for other people with the same issue

Answer (score 3):

Got it!!!

```
{% for category in form.category.field.queryset.all %}
    etc
{% endfor %}
```

Though I deal with a new problem now maybe you know why it would be happening. If I add a new category it won't show on the Select box, not until I restart the server.

EDIT: It works normally when I use it as normally as `{{form.category}}`

EDIT2: Edited now it works as it should.

Comment: You have to pass the query set dynamically that is available on runtime.https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#changing-the-queryset